# Hacer push a diferentes repositorios con diferentes usuarios de Git desde mi local

Tags: git, github

Llevo poco tiempo con Git y tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo en mi git Local dos cuentas de usuario asociadas a diferentes repositorios. Cuando hago git push a dos de esos proyectos no hay problema porque en la configuración global de git tengo ese usuario y email asociados a esa cuenta.

Pero en otro proyecto, he probado resetear el usuario y email en mi .git config de la raíz de ese proyecto pero aún así al hacer push me está dando error, 403.

¿Cómo puedo hacer push a diferentes repositorios desde diferentes usuarios de git en mi local?

Quedo a espera de vuestra ayuda, gracias por anticipado.

Comment: La cuenta de usuario local se usa para identificar al autor de los commits en el repositorio, el 403 esta ligado al sistema de autenticación del remoto, con independencia de tu usuario Git, ¿cómo estas autenticando al trabajar con el remoto https o ssh?

Comment: Hola Orici. Lo estoy haciendo con el remoto https. Hice diferentes pruebas pero sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en usar "diferentes usuarios de Git", pushear a diferentes remotos no supone en general mayor problema. ¿Has probado a configurar un usuario local, hacer lo que tengas que hacer, cambiar el usuario local, volver a hacer lo que tengas que hacer? No es lo más optimo, pero como dije, normalmente solo se tiene un usuario local.

Comment: Seguramente sea la razón. Tengo el usuario de config global 'User 1' (por ej.) y luego solo uno local para el repo que me interesa pero el error que me sale con el 403 es que el usuario 'User 1' (el global) me denega el permiso.
Es raro porque cambie el usuario/email para el repo que quiero subir.